# Django Edit Form Data: data is duplicated instead of being updated

Tags: django, forms, django-views

How can I update an existing record rather then add a new one which is my problem. Right now I'm trying to edit existing product data in the edit form and save the new changes. But instead of existing product data being updated, I get a new product, so everything is being duplicated. New product is created instead of its existing data being updated. What can I do to solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
@login_required
def edit(request, id=None):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProductForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        product = form.save( commit=False )
        product.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect( '/details/%s/' % ( product.id ) )
```

Eternicode, thank you for the great answer, the code now works fine and data is not duplicated as I save the form after the date is edited. Based on your reply, here is what works:

```
@login_required
def edit(request, id=None):

if request.method == 'POST':
    product = Product.objects.get(id__exact=id)
    form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)

    print "PRODUCT POST"

    if form.is_valid():
        print "Display Form"

        product = form.save( commit=False )
        product.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect( '/details/%s/' % ( product.id ) )
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to *update* an existing object, you have to provide that object as the `instance` kwarg to your form.  From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm):

```
>>> from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create the form class.
>>> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...         model = Article

# Creating a form to add an article.
>>> form = ArticleForm()

# Creating a form to change an existing article.
>>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

Comment: It worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH. The data in the form is now edited, saved and not being duplicated. Also, I found in the Django documentation that pk implies id__exact so I used id__exact instead of pk. Somehow pk was giving me errors.
Just wanted to show you my code in my second comment, and thank you again!

Comment: @login_required
def edit(request, id=None):

    #if id:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = Product.objects.get(id__exact=id)
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
        
        print "PRODUCT POST"

        if form.is_valid():
            print "Display Form"
            
            product = form.save( commit=False )
            product.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect( '/details/%s/' % ( product.id ) )

Comment: @Sophie, if you want to show the code that works, that's fine, but it would probably go better as an addendum to your question.  Also, don't forget to "accept" answers that solve your questions :)

Comment: Can you add the part to save it?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't ever retrieved the original object you're trying to update.  You need to do that first!